# Derivative of a functional w.r.t. a single point?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Lets say I have a functional $J:F\to\mathbb R$ where $F$ is the space of continuous functions (or differentiable functions, if you want) on $\mathbb R$.

then let's say for a particular function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, we calculate:
$$z=J(f)$$

Now suppose that I want to ask the following question: **how much does $z$ change, if we perturb $f$ at a single point $a$?**

So we kind of want:

$$\frac d {dy}J(f) \quad \text { where } f(a)=y$$

(This notation is probably not very good).

**Is there a concept that captures this?** I know that the Gateaux derivative looks at the change in $J$ that results from a perturbation *w.r.t. to a function*, but I'd like a concept that captures the change in $J$ as a result of a change in a specific point $a$. Moreover, we can then calculate this for the entire domain of $f$, and see how changes in the different values of $f$ result in changes in the total value of the functional.

Comment: How can you change a continuous function in a single point?

Comment: @md2perpe, you can't of course, but since the change is infinitessimal, we might still be able to talk about it. Moreover, you could do something like take the limit of the Gateaux derivative, letting the perturbation function go to the dirac delta function on $a$, or something like that? In any case, I don't know the best way to do it (which is why I'm asking this), but it must be possible I think.

Comment: Yes, you can think of the Gâteaux derivative as a function (or distribution) giving the dependency of a functional on the points. Also, physicists often define the functional derivative as $\frac{\delta J}{\delta f(y)} = \frac{d}{d\lambda} J(f(x)+\lambda \delta(x-y))$.

Comment: @md2perpe, is $\delta$ the dirac-delta function? How does this square with jabo's answer, which states that there is no canonical way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution. Note that the physicist definition is not mathematically correct since $J$ is not even defined on distributions.

Comment: @md2perpe, but extending the definition to distributions, would that cause any trouble mathematically?

Comment: If you could extend $J$ to distributions then there would still be the problem that the derivative (as a function of $a$) might be infinite for certain $a$. But this happens already when $f$ is disturbed with a function.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Do you have a certain application or example in mind? If so it would be interesting to hear about it and also about your expectations as to what the derivative was or what it would describe in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way you can make sense of this idea, but the notion of the derivative depends on a certain choice, which makes it non canonical.

The differential geometric view of a derivative is the following: Given a point $f\in F$ you define $$T_{f}F=\{\gamma{}\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow F \text{ differentiable}\vert ~\gamma_0=f\}/_\sim,$$
where you mod out the equivalence relation
$$ \gamma \sim\bar\gamma \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac d{dt}\gamma{\big\vert_{t=0}} = \frac d{dt}\bar\gamma{\big\vert_{t=0}} .$$
$T_fF$ is the *tangent space* at $f$and should be viewed as space of all directions in which you can change $f$. Now the derivative of $J$ at $f$ will be a functional
$$
J_*\colon T_fF \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad J_*([\gamma])=\frac d{dt}J\circ \gamma \big\vert_{t=0}
$$
You want to change $f$ at a single point $a$, so the question is whether this "direction if change" can be found in $T_fF$. You could for example put $\gamma^1_t(x)=f(x)+t g(x)$, where $g\in F$ is  a function with support only in a small neighbourhood of $a$. This defines an equivalence-class $[\gamma^1]\in T_fF$ and you might want to define
$$
\frac d{dy}J(f) := J_*[\gamma^1].
$$
But keep in mind, this will depend on the choice of $g$ that you make. For this to be a good definition for *all* possible $J$ one would hope that
$$
 \frac d{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}\gamma_t^1(a) = \frac d{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}\gamma_t^2(a) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \gamma^1 \sim \gamma^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad J_*[\gamma^1] = J_*[\gamma^2],
$$
But it is clear that the first implication cannot be true. It is however a valid question, in which cases the implication
$$
 \frac d{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}\gamma_t^1(a) = \frac d{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}\gamma_t^2(a) \quad \Rightarrow   \quad J_*[\gamma^1] = J_*[\gamma^2],
$$
holds true. For example for $J_1(f)=f(a)$ or $J_2(f)=f'(a)$ it is true. And I think it should not be too hard to prove that any valid $J$ is an expression of these two.

---

**EDIT 1:** In an effort to find a canonical tangent vector one could try the following: Put $g^\sigma$ the normal distribution with mean $a$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\gamma_t^\sigma=f+tg^\sigma$ be the associated curve, then you get a family of tangent vectors $([\gamma^\sigma])_\sigma\subset T_fF$. Does this have a limit in $T_fF$ as $\sigma \rightarrow 0$?

Unfortunately the answer is no. Usually one identifies $T_fF$ with $F$ via the linear isomorphism
$$
  T_fF\rightarrow F,\quad [\gamma] \mapsto \frac d{dt}\gamma
\big\vert_{t=0}$$
Now  $\frac d{dt}\gamma^\sigma
\big\vert_{t=0}=g^\sigma\in F$, but this does not have a limit in $F$ (equipped with the $\sup$-norm).

---

**EDIT 2:** The procedure described in the comments above invokes the Dirac Delta $\delta_a$ concentrated at $a$ and the question is whether you can extend $J$ to a larger function space $G$ containing $\delta_a$ in order to study the curve $t\mapsto f + t\delta_a$.

This question of extendability is a valid one, but cannot be answered in this generality, so it depends on which $J$ you are actually studying. For example the evaluation $Jf:=f(b)$ does not extend continously to distributions, not even to $L^2\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand the functional $Jf:=\int\phi f dx$ for a fixed $\phi\in C^\infty_c\mathbb{R}$ has an obvious extension to distributions.

When dealing with differentiation it might also be favourable for $G$ to be a normed space (I don't know too much about how well behaved the above described procedure is in spaces with a more difficult topology). And indeed there are normed spaces that naturally contain $\delta_a$ (i.e. you don't need to extend to all distributions), namely Sobolov spaces $H^s\mathbb{R}$ with order $s$ below a certain (negative) threshold. Of course you are also interested in nonlinear $J$s, but in order to give you an idea which functionals can be extended to $H^s$, let me note that the continous dual of $H^s$ consists of those linear functionals which are *integration against a weight $w\in H^{-s}$*.

Comment: What if we let $g$ somehow be a "circular function" (not sure if that's the right word), like the normal distribution. Would that pinpoint a unique derivative? This kind of reminds me of the Radon-Nikodym derivative for measure spaces: if the spaces of the two measures are $R^n$, then the Radon-Nikodym derivative is equal to $f(a)=\lim _{\epsilon\to 0}\frac {\mu(B_\epsilon(a)}{\nu (B_\epsilon(a))}$. In other words, there is a canonical sequence of sets (namely balls around $a$) whose ratio converges to the Radon-Nikodym derivative, even though arbitrary such sequences give a different value.

Comment: Maybe there is similarly, a canonical set of functions $g$ that would give a canonical value of that derivative (As I suggested we might require $g$ to be a normal distribution around $a$, and then letting its variance go to $0$).

Comment: No, that does not work, see my EDIT.

Comment: what do you think of md2perpe's comment?

Comment: See latest EDIT